# date not showing in mat field

Tags: angular, material-ui

I have a date for example "2005-12-24T00:00:00" - this is the way it come from the server,
using it this way show nothing to the user (after getting the data)

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>example</mat-label>
  <input matInput  autocomplete="off"
         placeholder="00/00/0000" type="date"
         [formControlName]="'example'">
</mat-form-field>
```

why?
what I missed?

Comment: You need to provide the ts file otherwise it is impossible to tell

Comment: An input type="date" need feed with a string in the way `yyyy-MM-dd`, an input type="datetime-local" need feed with a string in the way `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm` (you need remove the `T00:00:00`)

Comment: How you give value to the FormControl? instead give value,e.g. `data.date` use substring and give as value `data.date.substring(0,10)` or use split and give as value  `data.date.split("T")[0]`